# Odd python re.sub behaviour

Tags: python, regex, hyperlink

Recently, I tried some code that is supposed to create an html link if a certain syntax is entered. However, the resulting behavior is far from the one expected:

Input:

```
string = u"[id: 196]"
```

Code

```
reg = re.compile("(\[id:\s*(\d+)\])")
matches = re.findall(reg, string)
for match in matches:
    entry = object_pool.find(int(match[1])) // Just returns an object (already tested)
    string = re.sub(match[0], "<a href='/search#?id=%s?'>%s</a>" % (entry.id, entry.name), string)
```

I expect the following ouput:

```
<a href='/search#?id=196'>Production line n°4</a>
```

However, the actual output is [Production line n°4Production line n°4Production line n°4Production line n°4Production line n°4Production line n°4]

```
[<a href='/search#?id=196'>Production line n°4</a><a href='/search#?id=196'>Production line n°4</a><a href='/search#?id=196'>Production line n°4</a><a href='/search#?id=196'>Production line n°4</a><a href='/search#?id=196'>Production line n°4</a><a href='/search#?id=196'>Production line n°4</a>]
```

Is there something I didn't understand? Did I accidentally break the laws of programming and had the python eat its own tail in a loop of death? Do I deserve the death penalty? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you have in `match[0]` and `match[1]` ? why don't you use `match.groups()` ?

Comment: @alfonso.kim match[0] finds u"[id: 196]" and match[1] finds u"196". For some reason, it refuses  to use match.groups, saying it's a tuple, not regex hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, you don't need to use `re.sub`, since there is no replacement in `match[0]`.

try this:

```
reg = re.compile("(\[id:\s*(\d+)\])")
matches = re.findall(reg, string)
for match in matches:
    entry = object_pool.find(int(match[1]))
    url = "<a href='/search#?id=%s?'>%s</a>" % (entry.id, entry.name)
```

Comment: Well, I still need to get rid of the user's input (the goal being to "convert it to a link")
However, I found the solution : replace(match[0])

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `re.sub()` expects the first argument as a regular expression, where as `match[0]` is '[id: 196]', which means *replaces any of the chars with your string: i, d, :, space, ... Knowing that, you have a couple of choices. Since I don't know enough context, I cannot make a decision which is better, you have to decice:

#### Use the original 'reg` as first parameter

```
string = re.sub(reg, "<a href='/search#?id=%s?'>%s</a>" % (entry.id, entry.name), string)
```

#### Escape the `match[0]` parameter

```
string = re.sub(re.escape(match[0]), "<a href='/search#?id=%s?'>%s</a>" % (entry.id, entry.name), string)
```

#### Do a straight string replacement

```
anchor = string.replace(match[0], "<a href='/search#?id=%s?'>%s</a>" % (entry.id, entry.name))
```